# How to trap/listen javascript function or events in cefsharp

Tags: javascript, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to use cefSharp for a WPF application. [I can find "how to call a Javascript methods from .Net](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJS). But is there a way where I can get notified for Javascript functions or events in .Net?

e.g. if there is a Javascript function (with and without param) I can get the notification with or without values in .Net.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, YES!
There's bindings available for:

c# -> js use

> webBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);

js -> c# use

> webBrowser.RegisterJsObject(A_NAME_FROM_JS,
>   objectToBind);

Then from js you can call:

> window.A_NAME_FROM_JS.MethodOnObj()

and this will invoke the

> MethodOnObj()

on the passed

> objectToBind

It works like a charm. Let me know if you've an issue and I'll help further!

Comment: Thanks Penderi it definitely helped.

Comment: phew great to hear! We've got a FAST (renders <100ms) little UI working with CEF and have found it awesome. If you're stuck whack a question here and I'll try to help!

Comment: `webBrowser.RegisterJsObject` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

The `RegisterJsObject` and `ExecuteScriptAsync` methods are both deprecated now. I found another solution that `CefSharp` supports here:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent

More detailed information is here:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775#issuecomment-498454221

Essentially, from your `javascript` code on page, you can call:

```
CefSharp.PostMessage(someDataYouWantToPassBack)
```

And in `C#`, you register the event to your browser:

browser.**JavascriptMessageReceived** += OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived;

```
private void OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e) { }
```