# Catch Javascript mouse event in CEFSharp with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, cefsharp

I have a VB.NET Winforms application using CEFSharp and I am really very very happy with it.

Currently I am able to inject JS code into a target site to e.g. trigger functions or set textbox values, on the site, etc.
I also managed in the meantime to read values from e.g. textbox controls on the target website.

Now I am struggeling with further development:

I would also like to be able to react with my code on a javascript event on the displayed website.
(e.g. I could call a vb.net function in my code when a specific javascript event is fired on the website)

At the moment I am looking specialy to catch mouseup events and (if possible) also when the mousewheel is moved.

I already found 2-3 related references on the web and here on Stackoverflow in C# (including the example in the CEFSharp FAQ) but I am not entirely sure how to port it to VB.NET.  See here the mentioned example:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent

And here on Stackoverflow:  [How to trap/listen javascript function or events in cefsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067549/how-to-trap-listen-javascript-function-or-events-in-cefsharp)

So inprinciple it should be possible, but I am just lost in VB.NET translation.

Could someone point me to the right direction?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was ablte to port the official CEFSharp example to VB.NET with the help of some experts on another forum....

Here is what I did using Visual Studio 2017.

First I created the BoundObject class and added it to my program in which I was already using CEFSharp:

```
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Imports CefSharp

Public Class BoundObject
    Friend browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

    Public Sub browser_FrameLoadEnd(sender As Object, e As FrameLoadEndEventArgs)
        If e.Frame.IsMain Then
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.onmouseup = Function()
          {
            bound.onSelected(window.getSelection().toString());
          }
        "");")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnSelected(ByVal selected As String)
        MessageBox.Show("The user selected some text [" & selected & "]")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I added the following code to the end of my Public Sub New() function:

```
    CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = True
    Dim obj As New BoundObject()
    obj.browser = browser
    browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", obj)
    AddHandler browser.FrameLoadEnd, AddressOf obj.browser_FrameLoadEnd
```

The first line was necessary because I was using V63 of CEFSharp and there is a new way of handling bound functions starting with this version, but the old method is still usable by enabling the legacy binding method.

Also I had to change the event name, because it seems that the original event names in that C# example were renamed in newer versions of CEFSharp.

I tested this code with the Devtools console and I can call the bound.onSelected function and pass a string from JS to my vb.net application and make the textbox fire with the string received in JS from the website.

Hope this helps some folks out there, as there seem to be very little examples.